# Laravel - Retrieve foreign table name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I got and issue with relationships between simple data in a small laravel project.

I have a `recipes` table that list recipes, and I got a `recipe_types` table listing the type of recipe. In my `recipes` table, I got a column `recipe_types_id` that is a foreign key referring to the `id` column of the `recipe_types` table.

In Laravel, I have a view, where I want to list all the recipes, where I show the Recipe Name and the Recipe Type name.

A recipe can only have 1 type, but a type can be linked to multiple recipes.

Now in the Recipe model I added this:

```
public function recipeType()
{
   return $this->hasOne(RecipeType::class,'id');
}
```

I am pretty sure that the relationship hasOne is the right one, but because of the issue I have, I start having doubts.

and in my RecipeController, I retrieve all the post like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $recipes = Recipe::with('recipeType')->get();

    return view('recipes')->with('recipes', $recipes);
}
```

The issue I have right now, it's that when I display in my blade view the Recipe of ID 1 (with a recipe_type_id of 3), when I Use `{{ $recipe->recipeType->name }}`, that return the name of the recipe_type with the ID 1 and not the recipe_type with the ID 3.

**Here example of the data, current behavior and expected behavior :**

```
=== Recipe Table ===
{id: 1, name: 'Chocolate Cake', recipe_type_id: 3},
{id: 2, name: 'Carrot soup', recipe_type_id: 1}

=== Recipe Type Table ===
{id: 1, name: 'Soup'},
{id: 2, name: 'Main plate'},
{id: 3, name: 'Dessert'}
```

In my listing what I got now (the type ID retrieved is the ID of the Recipe):

- Recipe 1

  - Name: Chocolate Cake
  - Type: Soup
- Recipe 2

  - Name: Carrot soup
  - Type: Main plate

In my listing what I want and should have :

- Recipe 1

  - Name: Chocolate Cake
  - Type: Dessert
- Recipe 2

  - Name: Carrot soup
  - Type: Soup

Have you an idea of what I have been missing? I read the documentation, look on google and here on StackOverflow, I found solutions that I thought would help me, but they didn't, and I become frustrated not been able to complete what should be simple I think(?)

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have `Recipe` which belongs to one `RecipeType`.

Try like this:

```
public function recipeType()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(RecipeType::class, 'recipe_types_id', 'id');
}
```

In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) you can imagine your model `RecipeType` as `Post` and `Recipe` as `Comment`.

**`Recipe` belongs to only one `RecipeType`, `RecipeType` can have many `Recipe`.**

I hope I helped you to understand.

Comment: When I tried this, I got this error :
```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'recipe_types.recipe_type_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `recipe_types` where `recipe_types`.`recipe_type_id` in (1, 2)) ```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. You should use the `belongsTo` relation for your case.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I made the change, now `$recipe->recipeType` return null, but when I look in the database, all seems good, the ID of the type exist in the type database. I will try to find what is missing now, but it's weird

Comment: You are welcome. This approach is good with `belongsTo`. If the relation isn't good you should get some SQL error.

Comment: instead of $recipe->recipeType, use $recipe->recipe_type...

Comment: @S.Hossain I correct it after, now I use `$recipe->recipe_type`, but it still null. I'm still looking for why it's returning null, I have look over 10 google result with no luck so far. I about to let this down for today, I have lost 5 hours on this today, it was suppose to be fun xD

Comment: Can you do `dd($recipes);` before return in your controller and provide the result here?

Comment: @mare96 There is the result : https://pastebin.com/F0HmeW2C

Comment: Only what I can see here is, in my answer is `recipe_type_id` and should be `recipe_types_id`.